# Large volume Core Data search or an other alternative?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nspredicate

We have a requirement of searching product information for different combination of product,channel,regions for given date range.

Data volume around 1,46,000 (i.e. 146000) records. Each record is composed by productId, channelId, regionId, date and AUMValue.

Can we use Core Data just for search in a efficient manner using predicates? On the contrary, could you suggest any other alternative to search such large volume efficiently?

Comment: are you missing a zero, or is it 146,000?

Comment: Its 1,46,000 Is core data efficient to search or any other alternative?

Comment: Those commas make that number unclear. More or less than one million?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your number. Is it 1,460,000 records or 146,000 records? I have used core data with over 146,000 records and it's good, but not with 1,460,000 (one million four hundred and sixty thousand)

Comment: Its 1,46,000 :-). But can we use core data just for querying?I mean there are no update to objects and there is also no relationship association between objects.

Comment: @Vaishali "1,46,000" is not a standard number format and does not make sense. You need to clarify what the actual value is-- 146000, or 1460000, or something else?

Comment: Sorry for confusion..its 146000 i.e. 1 lakh 46 thousands number of records.

Comment: I see, standard in some parts of the world (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience Core Data will be the right choice to achieve a similar model.

Obviously, you should adopt a SQL store type under the hood since it has better performances.

If you create predicates in a correct way, you will able to improve performances during search. You could also think to index your store (i.e. some columns of your table, not all since they make the access to sql store more slow) to make faster the search.

I think that problems could arise if you need to import a lot of elements in your store. In this case background tasks wil be required to not freeze the main thread.

Hope that helps.